# How to queue multiple segues and execute them in a FIFO order in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, queue, segue, fifo

I have a function that runs a timer always checking for a change. If a specific condition is true, a segue is performed to another view controller.

```
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.checkForChange), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

func checkForChange() {
      if condition == true {
         performSegue(…)
      }
}
```

The problem is that I can have instances where 3 or more segues are supposed to be performed. Is there any way I could queue the segues and execute them in a FIFO order after each is unwinded?

Say the following happens:

- Event 1 Received
- Event 2 Received
- Event 3 Received

The queue of segues that need to be performed are:

- Segue 1
- Segue 2
- Segue 3

Then the following should be possible:

- Present segue 1
- Unwind segue 1
- Present segue 2
- Unwind segue 2
- Present segue 3
- Unwind segue 3